# Insert Trigger without duplicates by comparing last row from destination table

Tags: t-sql, triggers, compare, record

Hi I read two days and i cannot find solution, that's why i please for h
I'm trying to do trigger which insert data highest from last record for inserted table without duplicates.
I have destination table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[exported] ([Repair_Date] [datetime] NULL,
[idKards] [int] NULL,   [Position] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
[error] [int] NULL)
```

and trigger:

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[tr2] ON [dbo].[mes] AFTER INSERT 
AS
INSERT INTO  dbo.[exported]    
    ([idKard],[Repair_Date],[Position],[Error],[name],[model_name],[parent_number]) 
    SELECT c.idKards,i.[Repair_Date],i.[Position],i.error,s.name, mo.Model_Name,  pn.Parent_Number FROM inserted i
          left outer join dbo.test t on i.idTest=t.idTest
          left outer join dbo.Kards k on t.idKards=k.idKards
    where [Repair_Error] in (300,400) 
    and K.idKards > (select max(idKards) from dbo.exported)
```

Example data in dbo.exported - in this table all values are deleted except last:

```
Repair_Date            idKards  Position    error    
2012-10-10 00:03:25    91996    IC4303          4
```

When data is inserted to table dbo.mes (on which trigger is on) from another table (below example data):

```
Repair_Date         idTest  Position error  
2012-10-10 00:00:58 91996   C524     1  
2012-10-10 00:00:56 91996   C522     1  
2012-10-10 00:00:54 91996   C537     1  
2012-10-10 04:34:31 95694   P1104    1  
2012-10-10 06:48:33 97405   P1104    1  
2012-10-10 01:31:17 93088   P1104    1  
2012-10-10 01:34:04 92747   P1104    1  
2012-10-10 12:49:22 102773  P1104    1  
2012-10-10 14:19:03 102773  P1104    4  
2012-10-15 16:27:24 149693  P1104    1
```

Trigger should compare last idTest on dbo.exported with inserted data and add data without duplicates to table dbo.exported.
But it add all:

```
Repair_Date         idTest  Position error  
2012-10-10 00:03:25 91996   IC4303   4
2012-10-10 00:00:58 91996   C524     1  
2012-10-10 00:00:56 91996   C522     1  
2012-10-10 00:00:54 91996   C537     1  
2012-10-10 04:34:31 95694   P1104    1  
2012-10-10 06:48:33 97405   P1104    1  
2012-10-10 01:31:17 93088   P1104    1  
2012-10-10 01:34:04 92747   P1104    1  
2012-10-10 12:49:22 102773  P1104    1  
2012-10-10 14:19:03 102773  P1104    4  
2012-10-15 16:27:24 149693  P1104    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a left join against the inserted table, so there will always be rows returned by your query